# PHP array handling on-the-fly

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use the PHP `error_get_last()` function, but my question goes more to general handling of arrays in PHP.

```
error_get_last()
```

returns an array, but I only want the 'message' element from it.

So this works:

```
$ErrData = error_get_last();
$ErrMsg = $ErrData['message'];
```

but this is a syntax error:

```
$ErrMsg = error_get_last()['message'];
```

Can someone explain why, if `error_get_last()` returns an array, the elements cannot be referenced directly?

Surely I don't have to create unwanted temporary array variables whenever I want to access elements like this?

Comment: This is possible since PHP 5.4. In php versions before that, trying to access a element from something returned by a function is a syntax error.

Comment: Good pointer, but that answer states should be possible for PHP 5.4+.  I have 5.4.17 and still won't accept this syntax.

Comment: @stephen It's working great here in PHP 5.4: http://3v4l.org/7vYm6

Comment: Are you _very_ sure that's your PHP version? It works here in 5.4.21

Comment: My apologies, you are all correct, it *is* working OK on my 5.4.17.  I was having this problem yesterday, and since upgraded to OSX Mavericks which must have brought a new version of PHP with it.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @Sumurai8, thanks for the link to the article, amusing and therapeutic for the times when PHP leaves me baffled.  I am not a fan of weakly-typed interpreted languages generally, and prefer to live in .NET land.  But still we must always be prepared to work outside of our comfort zone...